# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) in the View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I understand what wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) means, but I don't understand why I am getting it for this line of code: `<% if current_user.try(:email) == Join.all(:email) %>` I am getting the error on `Join.all(:email)`
Basically, what I am trying to do is check to see if the `current_user.try(:email)` matches any of the email for `Join.all` The Join method is made up of strings that are :email. Here's what my table looks like

```
create_table "joins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `all` method doesn't take an argument. Try this:

```
Join.exists?(email: current_user.email)
```

Also, I'd recommend using a different table name than "joins", this is a commonly used identifier in ActiveRecord.

Comment: that works, except you need current_user.try(:email)

Comment: That would return true if no user is logged in and any Join models have a blank email. Is that really what you want?

Comment: None of them have a blank email

Comment: Ok, but I'd make sure there's a constraint for that at the DB level.